# Find date of the change in Last version

Tags: sql, date, bq

[image]

I'm trying to show the date where the last version changed - for example in customer ACA.. the version changed in 12/5/2022

BTW, I have more than one customers.

Comment: As you mentioned `SQL` and `bq` tag, what type of code you want write SQL or Python? Did you try to write any SQL code and what DBMS you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT MIN(date)
    , name
    , last_version
FROM Datatable
GROUP BY name, last_version
```

Comment: Why should anyone (want to) do something like? Did you test this _answer_?  Please,  see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=577d4407c9c218bef1d531b05e6d166f.

Comment: Ah my bad, i erased the date in the GROUP BY statement. Then it gives the first date for each last_version for each customer, which sounds like what is desired.

Comment: The question is about returning '2022-05-12', not the initial date '2022-05-10'. But is is pretty unclear why the initial date is not a change from noting to something 

Comment: In this case the query return `MIN(DATE)` of all versions, but not only last version as the description is. You can see here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a1af2c3a7797a9a809112ca83340873b

Comment: Well if you only want the change to the latest version, which I'm not sure is clear from the question, then yes :)

Answer (score 0):

In your query you can use analytic functions `ROW_NUMBER()` and `DENSE_RANK()` and your SQL query it would like this:

```
SELECT date_, name, last_version FROM (SELECT date_, name, last_version,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY last_version ORDER BY date_ ASC) as row_num,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY last_version DESC) as d_rank
      FROM <your_table>) WHERE d_rank = 1 and row_num = 1
```

You can see here SQL query result:

> db<>fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0fd33a31bdbd807926de8b2489e2883b

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate the dates to find the earliest per version, then the max of these is the date the version last changed:

```
select name, Max(last_version) last_version
from (
    select name, Min(date) last_version
    from t
    group by name, last_version
)t
group by name;
```